# Is there any Free & Open-Source TLS-1.2 implementation?

Tags: security, open-source, ssl

Looking for some free & open-source implementations of RFC 5246, i.e. TLS-1.2 and some of the associated extensions / related standards. Are there any ?

Found that OpenSSL doesn't have support for TLS-1.2, as yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNUTLS ([see here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnutls/)) includes TLS 1.2 AFAIK. And `mod_gnutls` does provide an TLS 1.2 endpoint to Apache 2 servers.

Comment: Wow. Fastest, perfect and complete answer. Voted-up and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, openSSL definitely DOES have the support for the TLS 1.2. beside this you can find a lots of TLS 1.2 implementations both free and commercial under [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TLS_implementations) link